# High frequency noise in G752VL on Ubuntu Gnome 16.04.01

Tags: 16.04, gnome, sound, alsa, asus

I just installed fresh Ubuntu Gnome on newly bought G752VL and found that sound isn't working correctly on Ubuntu Gnome 16.04.01. When I plug in any headphones there is a high frequency noise that gives me a headache (tested on Superlux HD681 EVO and Asus Cerberus). There isn't any problem under Win10.

To help with diagnose when I adjust systems volume (even mute it) the noise is at the same level of loudness. I suspect Linux drivers, but haven't found any alternative drivers for alsa1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu5. Please tell what can try to fix it or what else should I provide in this topic that could lead to resolving this issue.

- Kernel: linux-image-4.4.0.38.40
- Graphic: Nvidia-361.42-0ubuntu2

## EDIT:

New discovery. I tried to catch the moment when does the noise starts, so I turn on windows and switched back to Ubuntu to determine if it starts after grub, on kernel load or after login. But noise is gone. Don't know how, don't know why. Unplugging and plugging headphones back again didn't start the noise. Thank you for help. I did what @BarafuAlbino suggested and maybe restarting Ubuntu with all channels disabled helped.

## EDIT2:

It appears that rebooting from Windows to Ubuntu helps for the whole session. But turning on laptop straight to Ubuntu and boom the noise is back again. Similar thing is with keyboard's back light, can be regulated under Windows and last setting stays on in Ubuntu. So the problem remains, but has a long workaround.

## EDIT3:

I've updated kernel to 4.8 on Ubuntu Gnome and problem still remains. Now I'm writing from Live Manjaro Gnome whith kernel 4.9.20-1 and same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Run `alsamixer`, use F6 to select sound card in question, and use M key to disable all its channels. If the noise is still there, it is a hardware defect, and you have to solve it as such.

Comment: It didn't help. I'm writing from Windows 10 now with my headphones on and noise is gone (i can hear system notifications very loud). Will switch back to Ubuntu without taking headset off and will try to determine when the noise starts.